# Find all parent elements with absolute position

Tags: javascript, html, css-position

I'm writing some javascript code to move all absolutely positioned elements down 60 pixels (below a 60 pixel heigh div I'm displaying at the top of other pages on my proxy).  Here's the code I have right now (mostly borrowed from another question on stackoverflow):

```
function getStyle(el, prop)
{
  var doc = el.ownerDocument;
  var view = doc.defaultView;
  if (view && view.getComputedStyle)
  {
    return view.getComputedStyle(el, '')[prop];
  }

  return el.currentStyle[prop];
}

function runAfterLoad()
{
  var all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  var i = all.length;
  while (i--)
  {
    var topOffset = parseInt(all[i].offsetTop, 10);
    if (getStyle(all[i], 'position') === 'absolute')
    {
      all[i].style.top = isNaN(topOffset) ? '60px' : (topOffset + 60) + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this moves all absolute positioned elements down 60 pixels.  As it turns out, I found out that absolute positioning isn't actually absolute to the browser window, but absolute to a parent that meets some specific rules.  Here's a quote from another answer on here:

> This works because "position: absolute" means something like "use top, right, bottom, left" to position yourself in relation to the nearest ancestor who has "position: absolute" or "position: relative"."

So I'm looking for help on how to adjust my current code to only find the elements with absolute position that don't have a parent that is also absolute or relative positioned.  Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Every _HTMLElement_ has an [`offsetParent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.offsetParent) property, which tells you which _Node_ is used as the reference for that element's position.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use that fact to your advantage.  If you were to wrap your entire page in a `div` which you positioned absolutely (or relatively) with `top: 60px`, you would essentially move the entire page down `60px` at once.

This would also move non-absolute elements.  If this is not desired then this won't work.